# Display XML-string in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

From my backend I retrieve a string that contains some xml data. When i display this (now just with @Model.XM)L I see a nice long string that contains the xml data. Is there anyway to format this as a tree structure? Like with a jquery plugin or something? I tried some google, but couldnt find it.

On the page is also other data, it is not only the xml data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a recursive loop that will turn child nodes of the XML document into HTML list elements. Try something like this (untested):

```
var html = '<ul><li>' + xml.documentElement.nodeName + '</li>';
var html += displayTree(xml);
var html += '</ul>';

function displayTree(xml) {
    var str = '';
    if ($(xml).children().length) {
        str += '<ul>';
        $(xml).children().each(function() {
            str += '<li>' + this.nodeName + '</li>';
        });
        str += '</ul>';
        str += displayTree(xml.childNodes);
    });
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key is the

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

If you apply the above transformation to your XML, it will come out properly indented.
More details: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Comment: I agree that XSLT is the best method to use, but the above code would simply "pretty print" the XML. You would need to convert or add XHTML tags to ensure the output prints as a decent list in XHTML.

Comment: Why a list? The question only mentions a tree structure, I assumed it meant proper indentation